# WP DOWNLOAD MANAGER

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display the recent download posts on my homepage. with WP_query.

But i don't get any display or error.

WPDOWNLOADMANAGER is a download plugin that has it's own category.

```
   <?php
          $args = array(
            'post_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'document',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
          );
         $homepage_query = new WP_Query($args);   
          $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

      ?>
        <?php if (have_posts() ) : while ($homepage_query->have_posts() ) : $homepage_query->the_post(); ?>


       <div class="post-list-item">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-lg-3 post-item-type">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><button class="btn btn-green">View Document</button></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 post-item-panel">
            <div class="post-title">
                <span><?php the_title();?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-excerpt">
              <p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,160); printf( '<a class="read-more" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', get_permalink( get_the_ID() ), __( ' ...Read More', 'textdomain' )
); ?></p>
            </div>
          </div><!--//post-item-panel-->
        </div><!--row-no-gutters-->
      </div><!--//post-list-item-->

        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php
          if ( function_exists('wp_bootstrap_pagination') )
          wp_bootstrap_pagination();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. LOL got it all wrong again.

```
   <?php
                $q = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'wpdmpro',
                        'showposts' => 1,

                        'orderby' => 'publish_date',
                        'order' => 'DESC')
                );
                $z = 0;
                while ($q->have_posts()) {
                    $q->the_post();
                    ?>
```